# C-l multiple times doesn't work in Emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

The way `C-l` used to work with multiple presses was:

- Center window on cursor
- Move window so cursor is on first line
- Move window so cursor is on last line

Now `C-l` just centers, with multiple presses doing nothing.

I can do `C-u 0 C-l` and `C-u -0 C-l` but that's not as useful. Does anyone know why this would stop working? I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu Karmic from Jaunty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have been using a non-standard(?) function, mabye it was [recenter-top-bottom](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el).

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks! In fact, I was remembering functionality from my EmacsW32 installation - it was never in my Ubuntu Emacs, so that was just a red herring.

Answer (score 3):

With vanilla emacs23 built from source with default options, run with -q so no customizations are loaded, C-l works the way you describe - it centers/redraws, then puts the line at point at the top of the window, then puts the line at point at the bottom of the window.

Comment: @Justin Thanks, the problem was I was getting mixed up between Emacs22 and 23 :P I use 23 on Windows and 22 on Linux, and I was trying to use my Windows shortcuts on Linux.